# Proper structure of this sentence

Tags: grammaticality

To my knowledge, it is grammatical, but it looks strange to me as there are 3 participle clauses included in a single sentence.

> Eventually, the conclusion and recommendations have been proposed **based** on the findings **derived** from the literature **reviewed**.

Please advise me whether it is natural or not.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with past participles. Based, derived, and reviewed are close in meaning, and you have all three. All you need is *based on the findings* (derived) *from the literature* (reviewed).

Comment: Make sense, and thanks for the quick reply..!